# catching an exception in a loaded shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Is catching an exception thrown in a loaded shared library portable?
I've noticed that it works with `dlfcn.h`, but I wonder if this behaviour is in general expected, for example when using `LoadLibrary` on windows instead?

Example code:

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void(*dummy_t)();

int main()
{
    dummy_t f;
    void* handle;
    handle = dlopen("module.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    f = (dummy_t)dlsym(handle, "modulemain");
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "caught exception: %s\n", e.what());
    }
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

*module.cpp*:

```
#include <stdexcept>

extern "C" void modulemain()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("some terrible error occured");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine under Windows.

Comment: Propably the exception-implementation must not reside in the loaded library. The given example should thus work (standard-library exception), but not if a exception-subclass defined in the loaded library is thrown.